# Error in installing a package for python, which ask vc++ while I have

Tags: python, visual-c++, installation

I tried to install sklearn in python with this command in "command prompt" in windows:

```
pip install sklearn
```

I got this response:

```
 error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required.
```

[image]

So I installed https://files01.tchspt.com/temp/vc_redist.x64.exe
which is "Visual C++ Redistributables" and in my "program and Features" I can see it:
[image]

- My windows is 10 64 bit
- My python is 3.7.0 [MSC v.1914 32 bit (Intel)] on win32

Comment: Two steps. 1. install conda. 2. `conda install scikit-learn`.